How can I upload my BigQuery code to GitHub for free?
I can't seem to find a third party that is free, and the internal BigQuery to GitHub also requires payment.
I know I can use the command line, but I'm new at this and not well versed in the command line.
Are there any tutorials out there explaining this that doesn't require payment? Or any other options would be a big help!
I tried using Goliath and using the internal BigQuery export but both require payment.

Can you elaborate on your requirements and the purpose of uploading your code to GitHub?
Is it only SQL code that you are manually running in the BigQuery editor, and want to keep in GitHub?

Git on Windows has a simple GUI that you can start by typing git gui. Otherwise, there are plenty of other Git UIs that you can download eg GitKraken. Each of these will have a function to push to a remote repository, if you don't want to use the command-line to push.
